# Can anyone point me at a CMakeLists.txt example for a "GNU-style" project

Tags: project, cmake, gnu

Unfortunately, my Google search only turns up [CMake - Wiki - GNU_style_example](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake%3aGNU_style_example) which has a broken link to the example code.

I would like to use this format/structure for my project, but I'd like to see how the CMakeLists.txt files need to be set up to compile shared/static libraries and a number of executables.

Anyone use this style for their projects that could post an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going GNU-style, why not just use `automake`, which is designed to emit `Makefile`s that comply with the GNU standards?

Comment: @Jack: I've tried to use the automake/autoconf tools in the past, and never really liked working with them. I started working with CMake and have found it to be easier to deal with. Like most things, I guess it's a matter of personal preferences. I just wish that the documentation was a little clearer on some things and provided some real-world examples. The Wiki is not bad, but there are some things that I just have not been able to find as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Radio may be of interest: [CMakeWork](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/CMakeWork)